# Getting FilesMatch and Satisfy Any to work with sub directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I'm trying to lock down a tree of directories (but allow through image files) using the following .htaccess rule

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Test Sites. *Please Contact xxxxxxx for access.*"
AuthUserFile /home/www/testsites/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">
  Satisfy Any
  Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

However, when I try it, I'm still being asked to authenticate against images if the image is not directly within the httpdocs directory.

In other words

http://www.testsites.com/test.jpg would be allowed through, but
http://www.testsites.com/sitename/images/test.jpg is asking for authentication.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Do you have any other htaccess files?

Comment: No, that's the only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this alternative approach based on `mod_setenvif`:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$" ALLOWED

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Test Sites. *Please Contact xxxxxxx for access.*"
AuthUserFile /home/www/testsites/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Satisfy    any
Order      deny,allow
Deny from  all
Allow from env=ALLOWED
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure why this is happening, as the `<Files>` and `<FilesMatch>` is supposed to get applied to all the subdirectories. You could try using `SetEnvIf` instead to match against the entire URI instead of relying on the apache core to first map the URL to a file:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI \.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ no_auth=true

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Test Sites. *Please Contact xxxxxxx for access.*"
AuthUserFile /home/www/testsites/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Satisfy Any
Deny from All
Allow from env=no_auth
```